# PHP exit only current included script file from inside a function

Tags: php, function, return, include, exit

I know I can use `return` to exit current script file, but what if we want to exit current script from inside a function?

For example, we define a `exitScript()` function that prints closing html tags and exits current script file, but if we use `return` it only exits from current function. Also `exit()` terminates whole script not only current file.

Comment: You should only use `return` to return from a function. It is not ment to be a mechanism to exit a script.

Comment: I think you are looking for the **exit();** function .

Comment: @RiggsFolly There's a way to exit whole script from within a function, so it logically can/should be a way to exit only current script file from inside a function.

Comment: @Vidal `exit()` terminates whole script not only current file

Comment: `exit` terminates the script from whereever it is run [See manual for return](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.return.php) and [Manual for exit](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php)

Comment: Ohhh Do you mean you want to stop the execution of a file you have INCLUDED or REQUIRED? Is that what you are talking about??

Comment: @RiggsFolly Exactly

Comment: the question is not clear...

Comment: I am pretty sure that is not possible. Once you have included a file it is like it is part of the main script. There is no way of treating it like a seperate entity

Comment: @RiggsFolly It can be treated as a separate file as `return` exits only current file and `__FILE__` returns current included file's path

Comment: **return** exits a current method or function it does not exit any file or script only functions.

Comment: @Vidal I know, thats what I thought I was saying :)

Comment: @Vidal Actually if you do a return in the main flow of a code it will actually terminate a script.

Comment: this may have some serious logic issues if you want to terminate a script like that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Exceptions to do this, not particularly elegant, but this should do what your after, replace these methods.

```
public function fn1()
{
    try {
        $fn2 = $this->fn2();
    }
    catch ( Exception $e )  {
    }

    echo 'I want this to be displayed no matter what!';
}


public function fn4()
{
    $random = rand(1, 100);

    if ($random > 50)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        // I want to exit/break the scirpt to continue running after
        // the $fn2 = $this->fn2() call in the $this->fn1() function.
        //exit();
        throw new Exception();

        echo "This shouldn't be displayed.";
    }
}
```

Comment: The OP is talking about trying to exit only a file that has been included or requierd

Comment: Thanks it's a good solution. Also if we put last code inside a `finally` block it runs even fatal error occurs that is more than what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You can `return` from an included file to the 'main file', skipping execution of the remaing part after the `return`.

So this will output: `ABXend`, skipping `C`

**a.php**

```
<?php 
  echo 'A';
  include('b.php');
  echo 'end';
?>
```

and **b.php**

```
<?php 
   echo 'B';
   if(!x(6))return; //return here

   echo 'C';

   function x($num){
     echo 'X';
     if($num!==1)return false;
     }
?>
```

Comment: This needs to manually check all `x()` function calls and put `return` after them. Also we need to put `return` after calling functions that they call `x()` because we also can't use `return` inside those functions:)

Answer (score 0):

> I know I can use return to `exit` current script file

The above statement is not true, as has already been pointed out.

One solution for your question is to make use of....... [`goto`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.goto.php)!

But you don't call `goto` within a function. You would call your `exitScript()` function to print the closing HTML tags, and then immediately afterwards, use the `goto` operator to jump to the end of the included file.

A lot of developers would absolutely balk at the use of `goto`, but for certain situations and use-cases (and if you are an experienced developer and realise what you are doing), it can actually function as an efficient solution.

Probably though a better solution would be to break the included file up into more logical sections, and only include what you need in this case, and don't include the code that you don't want to run.